# Efficient YAML parser for IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, yaml

I'm trying to write a webpage that must support IE8+. A major part of this involves parsing retrieved YAML files. I found the js-yaml library and that works really well in Chrome/Firefox. However, parsing YAML files of ~1000 lines or more in IE8 is awful.

In IE10 calling jsyaml.load takes around 5s. For IE8 this is long enough to cause a 'script is causing IE to run slowly error'.

Profiling shows that we're losing a lot of time in .indexOf() - I'm using the implementation from es5-shims.js.

Does anyone know of a YAML parser that is more efficient on IE or a way of improving the performance of js-yaml on IE? I've found ways to fool IE8 into not displaying the warning but waiting 20s to parse a single file isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: I would consider server-side parsing and sending to the browser as JSON data if possible. Browser parses json natively which will always be much faster.

Comment: @petrch Thanks for the tip, the server-side parsing was significantly faster.